# Sane pattern for immutable pojos and single field changes

Tags: java, immutability

Usually I'd love all my POJOs to be immutable (well, to contain only `final` fields as Java understands immutability). But with my current project, a constant pattern is that I need to change a single field from a POJO. Working with immutable POJO's in this scenario seems cumbersome.

How would you go about having POJO's with bunch of fields and for each field you should be able to say "please give me a copy of this POJO but with this one field changed"?

Big plus here would be something that I can use with composable Functions. "Start with this immutable pojo, then basically push it through bunch of UnaryOperators and give me back new immutable pojo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a fairly common pattern - usually with a bunch of methods with a `with` prefix. Each `with*` method "changes" a single field, so you can have:

```
Person jon = new Person("Jon", "Skeet");
Person holly = jon.withFirstName("Holly"); // Holly Skeet
```

You can chain the calls together, too:

```
Person fred = jon.withAge(...).withFirstName("Fred").withJob(...);
```

Note that if you end up changing K fields in a POJO with N fields, you'll create K objects and need K * N assignments.

The implementation is usually just a matter of calling a big constructor with the existing field values and the new one:

```
public Person withFirstName(String newFirstName) {
    return new Person(newFirstName, lastName, job, age, ...);
}
```

I've used the term "pseudo-mutator" for this kind of method - it's a method which sounds a bit like it's mutating something, but it's more like it's creating a clone, mutating the clone, then returning it to you in a "frozen" state.

Comment: Damn you Skeet... Can I have your autograph? What's the official name (if any); never knew the name (it's not a fancy builder is it)?

Comment: @kolossus: No, this isn't a builder pattern - I don't know of a name for the pattern in general; as per my edit I call these methods pseudo-mutators, but that's *just* my name for them.

Comment: In my opinion, it's more of a variant of prototype (since each object can create changeable clones of itself).

Comment: I implement static Builder.from(person).withFirstName(firstName).build(); In Builder.from(persson) create new builder and copy all fields from the person POJO. Here is an article on the builder pattern with the optimized state: http://itzap.com/java-builder-pattern-with-shared-state/